# AWS Beanstalk Platform .NET Core running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/2.0.2 Publish Version Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, publish, .net-core-2.2

[image], [image]I am trying to Publish my Elastic Beanstalka .NetCore Project Using Azure DevOps Pipeline, But Azure DevOps Pipeline also comes up to Beanstalk Publish without any problem in Restore, Build, Publish Steps, but I get the following error in AWS Beanstalka Log file.
Project .Net Core 2.2
In the Document of AWS: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.dotnetlinux

```
[INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreBuildHooks
[INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/prebuild/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
[INFO] Executing instruction: CheckProcfileForDotNetCoreApplication
[INFO] checking application and updating executable file permissions...
[INFO] checking Procfile...
[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [CheckProcfileForDotNetCoreApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: there is no .runtimeconfig.json file for your single application. Please provide a valid application
```

Comment: Do you know where the `.runtimeconfig.json` file is?

Comment: Inside the Publish file. projectname.runtimeconfig.json exists. But AWS Benstalk does not see the file.

Comment: Meanwhile, Azure DevOps pipeline runs on AWS Beanstalk Platform with the same settings on Windows Server Core 2019 / 2.5.8.
AWS Beanstalk .NET Core running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2 / 2.0.2 server I get the error :(

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue.

I don't know if this is the answer, as I am new to AWS, but I have found:

1. The instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-core-tutorial.html only work if you create the Environment with a **Windows server**. It doesn't actually come right out and say that.  It says:

> 2. For Platform, select the platform and platform branch that match the language used by your application.

But in the next section, it says:

> IIS is the web server that runs the application on the Amazon EC2
> instances in your Elastic Beanstalk environment.

And IIS only runs on Windows. So this implies the instructions are for Windows.

2. If you want to use Linux, just use the site.zip file these instructions have you create and upload that. You don't need the manifest file or the zip-within-zip. Just upload the site.zip.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer,

I created a publish folder in my local using the command "dotnet publish -o site" and just zipped the contents. I did not zip in zip and added "aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json" file and I deployed AWS Beanstalka manually, but this time I got the following error.

**AWS Beanstalk Log;**

`[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [CheckProcfileForDotNetCoreApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: parse runtime config failed with invalid character '\ x00' looking for beginning of value`

Comment: The key part of this for me was `Windows server` - I originally launched a Linux instance and got the `there is no .runtimeconfig.json file` error.